# module 'pandas._typing' has no attribute 'FilePathOrBuffer'

Tags: python, libraries

When trying to import a darts atribute using the line

```
from darts import TimeSeries, concatenate
```

i get the error message

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas._typing' has no attribute 'FilePathOrBuffer'
```

Is there a fix for this?

Versions of what I'm using:

- `pandas` 1.5.2
- Windows 10 64-bit, ver 21H2
- Python 3.9.13
- `darts` ver 0.16.0

Comment: It seems like you're trying to get a set of outdated packages to work. If you want serious help with that, you should specify what operating system you are on, what architecture, what version of Python and what packages you require to be installed (and what versions). As it currently stands, your issue cannot be reproduced. However, if you can at all, you should consider upgrading to more recent versions of your packages.

Comment: thanks for letting me know to include the specifics of the version i will update the post and include them

Comment: `darts` is a fairly old module, and you have a brand-new version of `pandas`.  It's possible that `darts` needs to be updated.  You might file a bug report on the `darts` web site.

Comment: ive tried to update darts but that leads to me to another error"ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTModel' from 'darts.models'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like yourself, running Windows 10 64-bit, using a sufficiently up to date copy of Python 3.9 (I'm using 3.9.13), if I do the following:

```
virtualenv test_env
testenv\Scripts\activate
pip install pandas
pip install darts
```

This installs a large number of dependencies for `darts` and takes several minutes to complete, without errors or warnings.

The installed version of `pandas` after this is `1.5.2` and the installed version of `darts` is `0.22.0`. (it's unclear why yours would be `0.16.0`)

I can then run the following using Python:

```
from darts import TimeSeries, concatenate
```

And I get no error message. The error you're reporting cannot be reproduced using current and up to date versions of the packages you mentioned.

Why exactly do you have a reliance upon `darts` version `0.16.0` specifically?

Comment: the reason i was running darts at 0.16 is because i saw another person ask this online and the answer he got was to do ```pip install statsforecast==0.6.0``` and that specific version of statsforecast is only compatible with 0.16, if i try updating both items i get another error message that reads as "ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTModel' from 'darts.models'"

Comment: Well, as stated and shown above - if you use current versions, there's no issue. And `statsforecast` will already be installed (and up to date) as well, since it's a requirement that comes with `darts`. I'm voting to close your question as 'cannot be reproduced', since it appears you have no real reason to need old versions and the new versions all just work fine on the platform you're on.

Comment: If you need `statsforecast` to be some older version for some reason, you need to state *that* reason. And if that's because of more dependency issues still, you will find that people keep asking that question until you reach an actual functional reason - i.e. "I need it to be able to do [some thing] and only this old version can do it". And even then, rewriting your solution so that it works with the current versions of the modules makes a lot more sense - packages rarely lose functionality, they just change the way you need to do it (often improving them).

Comment: i dont need it to be some older version, i just get another error when trying it with the newer version. i will close the question and make another one with the error i get using the new versions.